# Can not get datarows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, datarow

The multi-part identifer "tblTask.Id" could not be bound.
What I´m I dong wrong?

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Value as int)) FROM [tblExtraFieldData] 
WHERE [tblExtraFieldData].[FieldId] = '10010' 
AND [tblExtraFieldData].[OwnerId]=[tblTask].[Id] 
AND [tblTask].[Status]=4 
AND [tblTask].[CustomA3]='Bygg'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: you need to add 'tblTask' in from cluase too Or just do inner join with 'tblTask'

Comment: @Kristoffer please see my ans which i already posted -:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Value as int)) FROM [tblExtraFieldData]  tble
INNER JOIN tblTask tblt ON tble.[OwnerId]=tblt.[Id] 
WHERE tble.[FieldId] = '10010'     
AND tble.[Status]=4 
AND tble.[CustomA3]='Bygg'
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Value as int)) FROM [tblExtraFieldData],[tblTask]
WHERE [tblExtraFieldData].[FieldId] = '10010' 
AND [tblExtraFieldData].[OwnerId]=[tblTask].[Id] 
AND [tblTask].[Status]=4 
AND [tblTask].[CustomA3]='Bygg'
```

possibly use first one.